# How to stop someone who can create strong illusions. (without killing him)

Tags: super-powers, evil

Let's say Mace can make someone think they're in Hell. He can make your worst nightmare come to life. He can create any illusion he wants. When someone is being manipulated they can't move.

He drives around in a car. People within his range believe they're attacked by zombies or worse. They start to attack each other. The effects fades away within a day.

How would you stop him without killing him?

Comment: How does he transmit the illusion? Is it via touch, electromagnetism, magic?

Comment: he uses his brains. He can make other people experience a psychosis.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information, especially with respect to the limitations of these powers and weaknesses. As it stands, however, tranquillising or otherwise rendering him unconscious would probably work.

Comment: Even brains is being really vague. You need to provide more info if you want valuable answers. Simple suggestion would be to make him unconscious, provided it is a conscious effort by him. Or can he just do the trick and walk away? Too many questions.

Comment: I'm not asking how he generates them but how he transmits them. Or does he e.g. touch the people with an opening in his skull, e.g. literally with his brain or makes them eat small parts of his brain or what? If so, maybe not so much the question, but the story has become a million times more interesting

Comment: When people come within his range he can manipulate their vision. He want the other people to see snakes. The victim is surounded by snakes. Howevr this is just in their mind. His range is around 20 meter

Comment: How many people can he affect at once?

Comment: eveyone, a entire city is in his controll. He drives around in a car. People within his range believe they're attacked by zombies or worse. They start to attack eachother. The effects fades away within a day.

Comment: You should edit these clarifications into your question, just in case the comments get cleared at some later date. You may also want to read [this meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions), which is about questions of this nature.

Comment: So there is no transmission? Fine. "When someone is been manipulated they can't move." How do they attack each other then?

Comment: oh, that's a big loophole. okay, they don't freeze. They can't kill Mace because he is not in their  "psychosis"

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I don't believe these to be duplicates. For one, that question places specific and significant limits on how the effect is applied, while the only limitation here is being "within his range." Still, in accordance with the Meta discussion linked by F1Krazy, I'm voting to close as _too broad_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a range on his skills, I hope there are other limitations on it as well. Like how many times he can use it in a short amount of time.

I would try to:

Use sleep darts with a gun or blow dart pipe.

Use a stumped arrow to knock him out.

Use gas or poison to knock him out.

Use a prostitute (or whatever kind of person he might hire) to get close to him and stab him with a needle coated in sleeping poison.

Make a bunch of iron balls with pointy ends, coat them in the same poison and shower him with. From a distance or via a trap.